# How to get youtube notifications

Tags: python, python-3.x, youtube-data-api, google-api-python-client

Is there's a parameter in Youtube-Api that I can get all the notifications coming from my channel?
For example, a user comments on my video then I want to get the user comment. But this seems impossible if I just get the comments for each videos.
What I want is to get the new comments coming from my channel using the youtube notification.
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/xMVm1.png
I'm currently using python.

```
from googleapiclient.discovery import build

api_key = '**'

youtube = build('youtube', 'v3', developerKey=api_key)

request = youtube.channels().list(
    part='statistics',
    id='UCoAlE_uI3N6MWuiQQc-EZgw'
)

response = request.execute()

print(response)
```

Answer (score 2):

Getting notifications for changes is called pub sub or push notifications.

[Push notifications](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/push_notifications) only support the following

Your PubSubHubbub callback server receives Atom feed notifications when a channel does any of the following activities:

- uploads a video
- updates a video's title
- updates a video's description

The YouTube data api does not have a pub sub endpoint for telling you when a comment was posted.

I would do a file.list and just poll for the information.

Comment: Thank you for answering, do you mean youtube API doesn't have the API for notification?

Comment: Getting notifications for changes is called pub sub or push notifications.   The YouTube data api does not have a pub sub endpoint for comments no.

Comment: Do you have any idea of how to configure the PubSubHubbubserver?